# displaying a user tasks

Tags: python, django

## model.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Task(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    objectif = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

## views.py

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter()
return render_to_response('home.html',{'tasks':tasks})
```

the problem is  it display all the tasks in the table but i want to display just the tasks of the user who is logged in
   how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view function (which you aren't fully displaying) has a `request` parameter. This parameter can be used to retrieve the current request's user. You should then use that to filter the tasks:

```
def the_view(request):    
    # .... 
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(username=request.user)
    return render_to_response('home.html',{'tasks':tasks})
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter by the user on request.user

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```